# External monitor to laptop resolution

Tags: laptop, resolution, external-display, sony-vaio

I own this laptop http://www.sony.co.uk/support/en/product/VGN-FW41E and I would like to add an external screen like this one [http://www.amazon.com/Dell-Ultrasharp-U2415-24-Inch-LED-Lit/dp/B00NZTKOQI](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NZTKOQI) but i am concerned about the resolution. My laptop has an HDMI port but can it support the resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most laptops of that generation will support up to two screens. And considering you have a Core 2 Duo CPU you will be limited to a max resolution of 1080p (I have a T9300 CPU and the max resolution a video can be streamed is 1080p) for video rendering. So, you will be able to play most of the videos, but you can run in some difficulties if the bitrate of the video is very high, or the compression is badly done. But to answer your question, if the video is playable on the laptop, it will be possible to watch in a 1080p monitor. If you are still unsure you can take your laptop and test it out at the store you plan to buy that screen.

Comment: And by saying two screens you mean the build-in and an external? I'm not going to play games or such, i'm interested in movies and programming. I'll take my laptop and visit a store but i'm also concerned about how crisp the screen will be since i have connected the laptop to a 1920x1080 via VGA cable and it was blurry.

Comment: That depends what type of chipset you have. But since it's similar to my laptop, I'm saying two screens. And yes, that means the build-in screen and the external one. As for the quality, you need to use the HDMI port, as it's the only one in your case that supports HD quality video transport.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its only a 1080p (well 1920x1200) monitor, which is well within the capabilities of the laptop.

You could have issues if you wanted a 2k/4k/UHD resolution monitor.

Answer (score 0):

If your laptop has a video output, then it's probably designed to be able to output video on a second screen and judging by the specs of your PC it shouldn't be a problem for it to do so (even in 1080p).